# How can I stop application until an observable thread ends?

Tags: java, android, observable, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm using **Retrofit** and **RxJava2**. In my application I have an `Observable` called `apiServiceGroups`. As I understand, the `Observable` runs in another thread while the application continues working in the main thread.

I want my application's main thread to wait until this part of code finishes running. How can I do it?

My code:

```java
disposable = apiServiceGroups.getGroupsList(String.format("{\"offset\":%s}", groupCount))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Consumer<GroupsListResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(GroupsListResponse groupsListResponse) throws Exception {
                                for (int i = 0; i < groupsListResponse.getGroups().size(); i++) {
                                    String currentName = groupsListResponse.getGroups().get(i).getGroupFullName();

                                    if (groupName.equals(currentName.split(" ")[0])) {
                                        familiar.add(currentName);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                Log.e("thro", Objects.requireNonNull(throwable.getMessage()));
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide all the views/fragments and show a loading indicator or progress bar until the API task gets completed in the accept method.

Once it is completed and you got your response, you have to hide the loading indicator and show the view/fragments.

API Call

```
  public LiveData<Boolean> apiCall() {
    MutableLiveData<Boolean> loading = new MutableLiveData();
    
      Disposable  disposable = apiServiceGroups.getGroupsList(String.format("{\"offset\":%s}", groupCount))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<GroupsListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(GroupsListResponse groupsListResponse) throws Exception {
                        for (int i = 0; i < groupsListResponse.getGroups().size(); i++) {
                            String currentName = groupsListResponse.getGroups().get(i).getGroupFullName();

                            if (groupName.equals(currentName.split(" ")[0])) {
                                familiar.add(currentName);
                            }
                        }
                        loading.postValue(true);
                    }
                , new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        Log.e("thro", Objects.requireNonNull(throwable.getMessage()));
                    }
                    }
                    });
           return loading;   
                    
    }
```

**In your Activity or Fragment**

```
  final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
                // Update the UI
            }
        };
        apiCall().observe(this, nameObserver);
```

**OR**

If you are not using livedata you can use callback from the API call response

```
 interface Response {
        
        public void onSuccess();

        public void onFailure();
    }
```

1. Implement the interface in your Activity/Fragment
2. Pass it to the API method
3. On success/failure response use the callback

   @Override public void accept(GroupsListResponse groupsListResponse) throws Exception {
   for (int i = 0; i < groupsListResponse.getGroups().size(); i++) {
   String currentName = groupsListResponse.getGroups().get(i).getGroupFullName();

   ```
                           if (groupName.equals(currentName.split(" ")[0])) {
                               familiar.add(currentName);
                           }
                       }
                       callback.success()
                   }
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i still don't understand how to connect progress bar and process which is running. What should i do to stop application and start progress bar?